# How can I get HTML code source of my opened page on Firefox in python

Tags: python, html

How can I get HTML code source of my opened page on Firefox in python?  I've tried **BeautifulSoup** but it's not getting my actual avtive, and opened HTML page.

Comment: All the browsers I am aware of, including FF, have a "view source" option.  You can then copy and paste this into a file or directly into stdin for your python script.  Is this all you needed?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can't obtain what you want because of javascript.

If you want to obtain the HTML of an "active" web page you should probably have a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It can simulate a browser, navigate to a given url and get the "active" HTML for you.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

source_code = driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pagina12.com.ar/'
my_page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_page.text, 'html')

your_html = soup.prettify()
print(your_html)
```

Don't forget to be sure libraries are installed

Comment: Hello thank's for all, but your codes gives me a "new" page, what I want is to get the source-code of a page  alredy opened, for exemple, If I want that, it is to get messages that I recive, and if I go to the url, not anny message is displayed. A live system maybe ? in real time ? thank's agane.

Comment: @Rafo554 Unless you are the author of the web page and able to put in a snippet of Javascript to do this, I think you are out of luck.